# Is it decidable whether a finite type scheme is proper?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, valuation-theory

Let $k$ be a field and let $X$ be a finite type scheme over $k$, explicitly given by finitely many affine patches which are $\mathrm{Spec}$ of finitely generated $k$-algebras, glued along other affine opens which are $\mathrm{Spec}$ of finitely generated $k$-algebras. Is there an algorithm to check whether $X$ is proper over $k$?

I assume the answer is yes, because I've never found it hard to do. But I just realized that both definitions of "proper" involve quantifying over very infinite sets: All $k$-schemes $Y$, if one is using universal closeness, or all maps from $\mathrm{Frac}$ of a valuation ring to $X$ if we use the valuative criterion. (We can make the valuation ring into a dvr, but that's still pretty darn infinite.)

Comment: You can use Chow's Lemma to replace your original finite type, separated $k$-scheme by an (explicitly) quasi-projective $k$-scheme.  For a given locally closed subvariety of projective space, it is fairly explicit to work out whether or not it is closed.  You do not need to use valuation rings.

Comment: @JasonStarr I was confused by your statement at first, since I thought Chow's lemma had as a hypothesis that $X$ is proper. I imagine what you mean is something like Exercise 18.9.H in Ravi's notes http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjan2915public.pdf ? Thanks, I think that works.

Comment: I think any approach (including Jason's, which is quite natural) would involve deciding first whether $X$ is separated.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Right, but that I do more or less know how to make computable. If $X = \bigcup U_i$, then the diagonal $\Delta$ is closed in $X \times X$ if and only if $\Delta \cap (U_i \times U_j) \cong U_i \cap U_j$ is closed in $U_i \times U_j$. First check that the given $U_i \cap U_j$ are affine, then check whether $\mathcal{O}(U_i) \otimes \mathcal{O}(U_j)$ generates $\mathcal{O}(U_i \cap U_j)$.